# jq - returns plain list instead of json array

Tags: json, jq

The below example returns a plain list instead of a JSON array for this sample JSON

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "one"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "two"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "tre"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the output I want:

```
[1,2,3]
```

But I get

```
1
2
3
```

with

```
[.items[] ] [] | [.id, .name]  | .[0]
```

Demo:   https://jqplay.org/s/YPG4I9BMDn

Comment: Answer helps overall, but my input is actually coming from another jq query https://jqplay.org/s/b9E5ah-VXZ  I would like to see ["1", "4", "7"] as the output.  I'm trying not to change the original query because I'm trying to validate its output.

Comment: I should have been more clear when I first posted. Thanks.
That example returns [1,2,3], I'm looking for [1,4,7] :)
Thank you for your help

Comment: See update to the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why take the trouble of taking a roundabout approach for such a simple filter? All you need is below. The `-c/--compact-output` flag will put the output in a single line

```
jq -c '[.items[].id]'
```

[jqplay - demo1](https://jqplay.org/s/YB7mMyh9-_)

To demystify your filter from the pasted link, `[.items[] ] []` will put the contents of `.items` in an array and will get it back from it. Then `[.id, .name]` will create multiple arrays with 0th element being the `.id` value and `.[0]` will get only the id values without them being put in an array. The approach doesn't make sense to me.

---

In addition to the OP, there was a post in the comments to get the first element from each of the arrays below

```
["1", "2", "3"]
["4", "5", "6"]
["7", "8", "9"]
```

which can be done as

```
jq -cn '[inputs] | map(first)'
```

[jqplay - demo2](https://jqplay.org/s/hg3MY-PkVx)

Comment: Thank you for the details.   I think in trying to simplify my example for the purpose of posting here I missed the main point I was trying to make (hence something simple being made overly complex)